# What connotation exactly does the word "noddy" have in British English?

Tags: meaning, british-english, connotation

I watched a BBC adaptation of Charles Dickens' *The Life and Adventures of Nicholas Nickleby* the other day, and came across a bit of dialogue I couldn't quite decipher:

> **A character named Squeers**:  I hope you didn't set out the good cut of meat.
>
> **His wife**: Do I look like a *noddy*?

What does *noddy* mean exactly? Is it archaic slang?  I'm guessing it means something close to "fool" here, but I want to be quite sure of the connotation of the word and when one would use it.

Comment: Don't forget that Dickens used 19th century slang.  And how could you not remember *Wackford Squeers*, surely the best name for an unpleasant teacher ever?

Comment: Modern equivalent would be "doughnut".

Comment: To any Briton born after about 1940, Noddy is Enid Blyton's simpleton hero, an odd little chap who muddles through by luck… not impossibly influenced by Dickens but clearly not vice versa.

So great is his - should that be her? - influence, it dwarfs what went before.  

Still Randy Fink's Tom Noddy stands not alone but references, inter alia, *My Lord Tomnoddy* (Robert Barnabas Brough (1828–60) http://www.bartleby.com/246/830.html

Much of the engine-searching you didn't bother with would have referred to them, and various Tolkien citations and no few You Tube videos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In today's British English you can hear *noddy* applied to a question or a problem.

> Q: I've got a question: when my phone
>   line is down, is my Internet
>   connection down as well?  I know it's
>   a noddy question!

You can even hear, speaking of someone:

> He's quite noddy.   Don't ask him too much!

The meaning is "*simpleton*".  It's not that of fool as in "*insane*".
This is confirmed by the main entry (there are no less than 5 for the common noun) in the OED:

> **noddy**, n. A fool, simpleton, noodle.

Here are a few quotes (including your own quote).

> **1530 J. Heywood Love (Brandl) 798** Why, where the deuyll is this horeson nody?    
>
> **1550 Bale Apol. 30 b,** O beastly **nody** wythoute brayne.    
> **1580 Lupton Sivquila 14** Mighte not he bee counted a verye **noddy**, that woulde pay suche a fine for a Farme?    
> **1621 Burton Anat. Mel. i. ii. iv. iv,** Soft fellows, stark **noddies**, and such as were foolish.    
> **1648 Gage West Ind. 101** In his carriage and experience in the World a simple **noddy**.    
> **1682 N. O. tr. Boileau's Lutrin iii. 94** And there they sneaking stand like baffled **Noddies**.    
> **1705 Hickeringill Priest-cr. ii. iii. 36** The cringing old **Noddies** and Cathedral-Men, that adore unlighted Candles at the Altar.    
> **1794 Wolcot (P. Pindar) Sun & Peacock Wks. 1812 III. 265** To credit such a tale I'm not the **noddy**.    
> **1838 Dickens Nich. Nick. vii,** To think that I should be such a **noddy**!
> **1871 B. Taylor Faust (1875) I. xxii. 197** A gray and wrinkled **noddy**.

Comment: That idea might be true and in 60 years of listening I've never noticed those modern examples. How do your 1530-1871 examples bear out the sense?

Answer (score 4):

*Merriam-Webster* defines it as “a stupid person”, while the *New Oxford American Dictionary* gas “(dated) a silly or foolish person (esp. as a general term of abuse)”. The connotation is really that of foolish, but I wouldn't use it nowadays.

The two sources differ on the origin, though neither is categorical: for *Merriam-Webster*, it is “probably short for obsolete *noddypoll*, alteration of *hoddypoll* (fumbling inept person)”, while *NOAD* says “perhaps from the verb *nod* + *-y*”.

Answer (score 3):

The use of Noddy as a fool is probably quite rare, at least in any bits of England I've lived in.
More common is Noddy as simple or easy - eg. "a Noddy question on an exam"

Comment: Uh… mgb, how is Noddy "as a fool" different from "as simple or easy - eg: 'a Noddy question on an exam"? Don't you think 'a Noddy question on an exam' means, specifically, one that even a fool could answer?

Answer (score 2):

The etymology is well described above, but noddy in modern parlance is probably more likely to evoke "Make Way for [Noddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noddy_%28character%29)," a children's show about a creepy looking puppet that walks.

Comment: 'In modern parlance'? As your reference shows, Noddy is more than 60 years old.

Comment: More modern than _Nicholas Nickleby_

Comment: Apparently the children show continues to run to this day http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Noddy_300.jpg

Comment: "60 years old" ... what does that mean?  How old is Mickey Mouse?  Of course, obviously, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I was growing up in North London, it was a common term for a policeman, especially a motorcycle policeman.

Locally at any rate, it's a term for shots of a TV interviewer to be edited-in to a story to show their agreement with, understanding of or sympathy with the interviewee. Often also applied to the obligatory background party hacks showing universal agreement with or endorsement of their political masters and mistresses.

It also has some application in the "adult movie" industry, or so I am led to believe.

Answer (score 0):

In modern usage, as an adjective, I think it has also come to mean insignificant or trifling.

Answer (score -1):

"Giving noddy" also means fellatio. This meaning is becoming increasingly popular, especially in youth culture. Writers beware of which connotation you wish to express.

Comment: Welcome to English.stackexchange. In common with all Stack Exchange sites this is strictly a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. What you have written is clearly not the answer to this question, it is a side comment. Also, good answers on this site have evidence (i.e. references) to back them up.